# "Ask company X about this job..." validation really suxors

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The validation on the ask company X a question (before applying) really suxors.  Couple of things I've noticed:

- Entering an empty space and clicking submit - actually submits the form, there is no trim() function or anything
- Once you submit the question, you can no longer submit any more questions to that company, why?
- Here's the worst one, once you submit a question to one company and you go to submit one to another company here's what happens:

[image]

Notice the send message button, its disabled, and there doesn't appear to be a way to reenable it unless I perform some sort of client side hack.  The steps to reproduce this is...

- Ask a question to one company
- Go to a totally different company and try to ask them a question
- Voila issue

Comment: Man, just start working for Quicken Loans already :P

Comment: No thanks, I'm using them as a sample.

Comment: Noted. Added to the bug tracker. I will assume for now this will be fixed before the wider release.

Comment: #1 fair point. #2 will require a deeper re-org of our messaging code and policies - will have to defer that for now. #3 is repro'd. Fixes for #1 and #3 forthcoming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix is building out now. Thanks.